# Need to run marked tests dynamically using py.test

Tags: automated-tests, pytest

I was looking for a way to run selective tests on run time. Found each test can be marked using `@pytest.mark`.

```py
import ...

@pytest.mark.feature1

@pytest.mark.priority1

or something like : @pytest.mark(Feature.feature1, Priority.priority2)

def m1

def m2

..
```

Now I need to run test scripts which are marked as `feature1`, without giving the script name.
Something like (not sure about command)

```
py.test -m "feature1"
```

It should pick all scripts which are marked as `feature1` in test suite as other scripts might be marked as `feature2..n` as well.

Please suggest:

1. above way to mark tests and pick on run time is suggested or not?
2. Do I need to have classes to mark test? I believe above way will mark complete test.
3. What is the command to pick marked test from complete test suite?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for is the **-m** option of py.test.

After marking tests with different labels (using the @pytest.mark.*label*, where *label* is feature1 or whatever you want), you can run all the feature1 marked tests using:

```
py.test -m feature1
```

This will run only the tests marked with the 'feature1' label.

Marked tests can be combined:

```
py.test -m "feature1 or feature2"
```

or skipped using `not`, such as

```
py.test -m "not (feature1 or feature2)"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [@pytest.mark.skipif](https://pytest.org/latest/skipping.html) 
 This will skip tests according to condition you put in marker . You can use a string in if condition to skip the desired tests

Comment: Thakd for the comment MAchintosh_89 but I am looking to have automation tags on scripts for selecting dynamically. Skipif will just skip script.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, in that case this might be the answer **pytest -k string**  select all tests that contains the string in their name and run it

Comment: That will work till one extent. But my use case is I want to run all scripts which are of feature1, is of high priority and is tagged as smoke script. so each script might have something like this  @pytest.marks(feature1, high, Smoke)..  Please have a look at "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23533869/how-to-apply-pytest-marks-on-python-class-level"  as well.. I found some solution to above problem but have some issue there as well.